# Sync Code Between EC2's [Rsync/SSH]

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, svn, rsync

I have a variety of EC2 boxes inside an ELB, one of which is used for SVN exclusively.  I currently have a script that gets called as part of the post-commit hook which is meant to sync files between various EC2's.  The problem is that new files/folders are sync'd but deletes are not.  I want to sync everything, deletes (files/folders), updates, etc.

Here is what I am using currently:

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -avz ~/testing/* -e "ssh -i ./testing.pem" ec2-user@ipgoeshere:/home/ec2-user/testing
```

So again, I want everything from the source to be sync'd over to the EC2 including additions, changes, deletes, etc.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You must use `--delete` switch to make rsync delete extraneous files.

Comment: rsync -rtvu --delete ~/testing/ -e "ssh -i ./testing.pem" ec2-user@ipgoeshere:/home/ec2-user/testing/ -- did the trick!

Comment: I should probably ask this as a follow up question but how do I restrict certain files from being sync'd over?  Obviously any of the .svn stuff shouldn't go along w/ the sync. @ThoriumBR

Comment: ^--- Answer to that here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56131/rsync-except-svn-folders-and-their-sub-contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sync and delete files, and exclude some files, you can use `--delete` and `--exclude`:

```
rsync -rtvu --delete --exclude '*.svn' ~/testing/ -e "ssh -i ./testing.pem" ec2-user@ipgoeshere:/home/ec2-user/testing/
```